# Firebase Firestore : Key name is variable.No setter field for santosh@gmail.com found

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

How can I define a model for this type of data? I want to put these in a recycler view in an adapter.

Comment: I recommend anonymizing the data here and not posting real emails (if they are real)

Comment: Please remove the image from your post and include a structure as text. Block out the email addresses; xxxxx@somedomain.com. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then clarify your question as the model structure will depend on what you want to do with it and what the relationship is between its properties. As it is, we have no idea why you would want to store three email addresses in a class.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the feedback. I'll keep that in mind when posting questions hereafter. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create at Firebase a **collection** and than a **document** for each model (document = object in your code). After this you can request all the items in your collection through Firebase API.

```
db.collection("cities")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        // where you iterate over every document and create an object for each 
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)